# Increase font size in Ghidra

Tags: ghidra

For the record, this is a question I often see:

Especially when using a high-resolution display, fonts and other UI elements can appear extremely small. How can they be enlarged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, just edit the file:

`\GHIDRA_DIR\support\launch.properties`

and add the line:

`VMARGS_WINDOWS=-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2`

A similar command can be used for other systems.